# How to get $F_k=E_k\setminus (\cup_1^{k-1}E_j)=E_k\cap (\cup_1^{k-1}E_j)^c$?

Tags: real-analysis

> In Folland's textbook: states that
>   $$F_k=E_k\setminus (\cup_1^{k-1}E_j)=E_k\cap (\cup_1^{k-1}E_j)^c$$

But I feel like $E_k\setminus (\cup_1^{k-1}E_j)=\cap_{j=1}^{k-1}(E_k-E_j)$. Is not it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $A\setminus B$ = $A\cap B^c$. Your equality is also true.

Edit: I'll use the associativity of the intersection.

$\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} (A\E_{i})$ = $\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} (A \cap E_{i}^c)$ =

($\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} A$) $\cap$  ($\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} E_{i}^c)$)=

$A$ $\cap$ ($\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} E_{i})^c$.

Comment: How to get one from the other one?

Comment: Use Morgan's law and Distribution. No big deal.

Comment: No. I mean that from $\cap_{j=1}^{k-1}(E_k-E_j)$ to get $E_k\cap (\cup_1^{k-1}E_j)^c$?

Comment: Please give a moment.

Comment: I have written proof. I don't know how to post a picture. Then it would be easier.